# Periodicity of a Function Given the Functional Equation $f(x+a)=\frac12+\sqrt{f(x)-\big(f(x)\big)^2}$

Tags: functions, functional-equations, periodic-functions

Let $f$ be a real valued function defined for all real numbers $x$ such that for some positive constant $a$ the equation $f(x+a)=\frac12+\sqrt{f(x)-\big(f(x)\big)^2}$ holds for all $x$. Then prove that $f$ is periodic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x+a)\big(1-f(x+a)\big)\\
=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{f(x)\big(1-f(x)\big)}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}-\sqrt{f(x)\big(1-f(x)\big)}\right)\\
=\frac{1}{4}-f(x)\big(1-f(x)\big)$$
$$\therefore f(x)\big(1-f(x)\big)+f(x+a)\big(1-f(x+a)\big)=\frac{1}{4}$$
$$\therefore f(x+a)\big(1-f(x+a)\big)+f(x+2a)\big(1-f(x+2a)\big)=\frac{1}{4}$$
Thus subtracting the above two equations
$$\therefore f(x)\big(1-f(x)\big)=f(x+2a)\big(1-f(x+2a)\big)$$
$$\therefore f(x+3a)=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{f(x+2a)\big(1-f(x+2a)\big)}\\
=\frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{f(x)\big(1-f(x)\big)}=f(x+a)$$
$$\therefore f(x+2a)=f(x)$$