# How to prove a function is periodic from a given functional equation?

Tags: functional-equations

> Given that $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, and that for some $a \in \mathbb R$, $f(x+a)={1\over 2}+\sqrt{f(x)-f^3(x)}$; prove $f(x)$ is a periodic fucntion.

I know that to prove a function is periodic one needs to prove $f(x+bK)=f(x)$ for all $b \in \mathbb Z$, and the period is $K$

But how can I solve this problem?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned it's "for all $x\in \mathbb R$" and $b$ shouldn't be there.

Comment: Does the observation $f(a)=\frac{1}{2}$ help? I dunno

Comment: @GitGud If he wrote $b\in \mathbb{Z}$ then both definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @user3313320 Even if it helps, it's not necessarily true.

Comment: @GitGud Plug in $x=0$

Comment: Wait a min...$f^3(x)$ means $f(f(f(x)))$ or $(f(x))^3$?

Comment: @user3313320 You're right about the definitions being equivalent. As for plugging in $0$, then one either gets $f(a)=\dfrac 12 +\sqrt{f(0)-(f(0))^3}$ or $f(a)=\dfrac 12+ \sqrt{f(0)-f(f(f(0)))}$. How to get $f(a)=\dfrac 1 2$ in either case?

Comment: @GitGud Oops sorry. Seems like I have simply and mistakenly regarded $f(0)=0$

Comment: In fact it seems clear $f(x)\in [\frac12,1]$ for all reals.

Comment: Seems similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1147980/periodic-function-with-a-given-functional-equation/1322624#1322624

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) = \frac 12 + \sqrt{x - x^3}$.

Forall $x \in \Bbb R$, $f(x) = g(f(x-a)) \ge 1/2$.
Also, since $f(x+a) = g(f(x))$ exists, we must have $f(x)-f(x)^3 \ge 0$, hence $f(x) \le 1$

Therefore, $f(x) \in [0.5 ; 1]$ forall $x \in \Bbb R$.

$g$ is increasing from $x=1/2$ (where $f(1/2)>1$) to $x=1/\sqrt 3$ then decreases to $x=1$ (where $f(1)=1/2$).

We can compute and see that $0.83 > 1/\sqrt 3$ and $g(0.83) > 1$, so for any $x \in [0.5;0.83]$, $g(x) > 1$.

Therefore, $f(x) \in [0.83 ; 1]$ forall $x \in \Bbb R$ (or else $f(x+2a)$ wouldn't exist)

$g'(x)$ is decreasing on that interval, and $g'(0.83) < -1$, so forall $x \in \Bbb [0.83;1]$, $g'(x) \le g'(0.83) < -1$.

In particular we have $|f(x+2a) - f(x+a)| \ge |f(x+a)-f(x)||g'(0.83)|$.

Let $M = \sup_{x \in \Bbb R} |f(x+a)-f(x)|$. Since $f(x) \in [0.5;1]$, we obviously have $0 \le M \le 0.5$.
But we also have $M \ge M |g'(0.83)|$, which is impossible unless $M=0$.

Therefore $f(x+a) = f(x)$ forall $x \in \Bbb R$ . And in fact $f$ is constant and its value is the unique fixpoint of $g$ in $[0.83;1]$